# Job does not get picked up by worker in bullmq

Tags: node.js, express, message-queue, bull, bullmq

I a using bullmq with ioredis in an express server. I have about 5 queues for different tasks. But none of the jobs seem to be getting picked up by workers.

I have checked the redis connections, and possible typoes in the queue names. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try this 
const queueName = 'myqueue';
const myQueue = new Queue(queueName, { connection });
new Worker(queueName, async (job)=>{}, { connection });